# How to detect language from URL in Sinatra

Tags: url, internationalization, url-routing, sinatra, padrino

I have a multi-language website and I'm puting the language in the URL like domain.com/en/. When the user doesn't put the language in the URL I want to redirect him to the page in the main language like "domain.com/posts" to "domain.com/en/posts". Is there an easy way to do this with Sinatra?

I have more than one hundred routes. So doing this for every route is not a very good option.

> get "/:locale/posts" do... end
>
> get "/posts" do... end

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a before filter, somewhat like this:

```ruby
set :locales, %w[en sv de]
set :default_locale, 'en'
set :locale_pattern, /^\/?(#{Regexp.union(settings.locals)})(\/.+)$/

helpers do
  def locale
    @locale || settings.default_locale
  end
end

before do
  @locale, request.path_info = $1, $2 if request.path_info =~ settings.locale_pattern
end

get '/example' do
  case locale
  when 'en' then 'Hello my friend!'
  when 'de' then 'Hallo mein Freund!'
  when 'sv' then 'Hallå min vän!'
  else '???'
  end
end
```

With the upcoming release of Sinatra, you will be able to do this:

```ruby
before('/:locale/*') { @locale = params[:locale] }
```

Comment: @Konstantin: is there a way to make it work for root urls? (ex: / and /en/)

Comment: maybe with "get '/?:locale?/' do" ? but that way it is giving always the default locale, and I have to hack it a little to behave like the other routes. is there any good practice about this?

Comment: @David change the regex to `/^\/?(#{Regexp.union(settings.locales)})(\/.*)$/` and it works for `/` and `/en/`