# Sinatra routes and i18n

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```
set :locales, %w[en it]
set :default_locale, 'it'
set :locale_pattern, /^\/?(#{Regexp.union(settings.locales)})(\/.+)$/

helpers do
  def locale
    @locale || settings.default_locale
  end
end

before('/:locale/*') { |params| @locale = params.first } # params shouldn't be a Hash?
```

I cannot get other pages starting with a /en/:

```
get '/attivita/:activity' do |activity|
  erb "attivita/#{activity.to_sym}".to_sym
end
```

Should I pest routes with :locale anywhere? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `before` block gives me a `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` on `Sinatra 1.1.3`.

With the `before` from [How to detect language from URL in Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104658/how-to-detect-language-from-url-in-sinatra) works for me:

```
before do
  @locale, request.path_info = $1, $2 if request.path_info =~ settings.locale_pattern
end
```