# How to integrate the language in the URL in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, url, internationalization, sinatra, rails-i18n

I have an application with many languages and now I want to integrate in the URL the language. Something like this: `https://example.com/en/main/cars` `https://example.com/fr/main/cars` and so on. The application works perfectly for every language, only that the language is missing in the URL.

I checked already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104658/how-to-detect-language-from-url-in-sinatra) and [this](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/development/i18n) but I did not have success. I will appreciate any help.

In `helpers.rb` I have:

```
def set_locale( new_locale )
  allowed_locales = %w[ de en fr it sk ]
  if allowed_locales.map{|l| l.to_sym }.include?( new_locale.to_sym )
    session[:locale] = new_locale.to_sym
  else
    session[:locale] = default_locale
  end
end
alias_method :set_lang, :set_locale

def locale
  session[:locale] || default_locale
end

def default_locale
  :de
end

def t( *args )
  I18n.locale = locale
  I18n.t( *args )
end

def l( *args )
  I18n.locale = locale
  I18n.l( *args )
end
```

In `app.rb` I define something like this:

```
Class Something < Sinatra::Application
  helpers Sinatra::Something::Helpers
  I18n.load_path += Dir[File.join(settings.root, 'locales', '??.yml').to_s]

  before "/*" do
    set_locale params[:locale] if params[:locale]
    set_locale params[:lang]   if params[:lang]
    set_locale params[:l]      if params[:l]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you showed, you are nowhere setting the first part of your url as the language param. Try to add the before-filter from the doc you linked:

```
before '/:locale/*' do
    I18n.locale       =       params[:locale]
    request.path_info = '/' + params[:splat ][0]
end
```

Alternatively, you can edit your routes to include and name this parameter.